# How do I copy cells so that only the sheets where they reference from is changed?

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

I have a `expenses` sheet, and other sheets named `Jan`, `Feb`, etc. These sheets are identical except for their numerical values.

In the `expenses` sheet I want to have columns, each of them applying to a separate month, and I want these columns' cells to reference information inside the relevant month's sheet.

For example, for January, I will have cells of the form `=SUM('Jan'!$D2:$Z2)`. I of course have many such cells (each referring to a different row in `Jan`). How can I generalize this so that I'll have this behavior for the other months? That is, so that the relevant cells will be of the forms `=SUM('Feb'!$D2:$Z2)`, `=SUM('Mar'!$D2:$Z2)` etc.

Or, to summarize the question: How can I copy multiple cells that reference another sheets so that only the sheet to which they are referenced is changed?

Comment: Welcome. Your explanation of the layout of your spreadsheet and the `sum` formulas is difficult to follow and visualise. Would you please edit your question to provide an example of the expenses sheet as well as a monthly sheet containing some data, and the relevant `sum` formula. Would you please also summarise your research and any work that you have done to solve your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put the names of the months/sheets in a column, let's say "jan" is in A2, you can use a formula in B2 that uses the value in A2, indirect and concatenate to find the sum of one sheet:

```
=SUM(indirect(concatenate(A2, "!$D2:$Z2")))
```

Now you can put feb, mar etcetera in the columns below, and drag/copy the formula to get the results for the other months too.

Try it out in [this little demo](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1l7A0w6gGD0ewj6KUG_gEk4tCS_Ar1H3l0Gzh9D-MkuA/edit?usp=sharing) i prepared for you.

Comment: Perfect, thank you!